# unable to convert string to hex in PERL

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl

I am parsing a file which consists of decimal as well as hexadecimal values separated by ":":

```
foreach $line (<INFO>)  { 
    my ($seq_no, $size_in_bytes, $Hitcount, $buffer) = split /:/, $line;

    # $size in_bytes is a hexadecimal value.

    print "check 1 $size_in_bytes\n";      # printing some value in hexadecimal
    $size_in_bytes = hex($size_in_bytes);
    print "check 2  $size_in_bytes\n";     # Printing ZERO??
}
```

I tried below approach also but still it is giving ZERO only.

```
$dec_num = sprintf("%d", hex($num));
```

Can you please tell me how can I convert string to Decimal

Comment: Can you upload a few example lines?  What's the connection to Apache/modules?

Comment: debug the values being passed to `hex()` - for instance, it will return 0 if there are leading spaces: `hex(" 12") == 0`, but `hex("12") == 18`. There is no need to use `sprintf` to stringify a number.

Comment: add `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=$Data::Dumper::Terse=1; print "check 0 " . Dumper($size_in_bytes);` and show us at least a few lines of input and output

Comment: I suggest there may be spaces before or after the colons in your data. Try splitting like this `split /\s*:\s*/, $line`.

Comment: thanks @user5402 i used the trim function and it worked.

Comment: @user991282: It's best to get the `split` right in the first place than do it wrong and hack a fix.

Comment: @user991282: Which `trim` function do you mean? The only one I know is `String::Util::trim`, and if you're loading a whole module just to fix a badly-coded `split` then it's *certainly* the wrong approach

Comment: @Borodin I used `code`$size_in_bytes =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; to trim spaces.

Comment: Okay, but still it is best to get the `split` right. Have you tried writing it as in my solution below? There should then be no need to trim anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the problem is with superfluous spaces in your fields, you should split like this instead

```
split /\s*:\s*/, $line
```

That way the spaces will be removed if there are any, but the `split` will still work fine if not.